# Inline style using javascript - design approach for Adobe Experience Manager(cms)

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, stylesheet, aem

I am fixing a bug for a custom component my company got from Adobe. 
Details about this component : It is a carousel, with the navigator[carousel navigator] numbered. So the carousel is building its navigator completely using javascript.

Structure of the divs
`<div class="carousel"><div class="pane"><div id="textimage_xyzzz"></div><div class="grotatorNav"></div></div></div>`

so the bug is 
they have designed the '.grotatorNav' such that its 'position is absolute' and 'top is 160px' and the '.carousel' is always fixed to 'height : 300px and width: 700px' grotator is absolute to carousel and always at the same height of 160px.

I wanted to adjust this by using '.pane' height as it is changing as per the "textimage" in the pane [text image is another component where the CMS author can adjust],

so what I have done is

```
var heightOfPane = $('.pane').height();
$('#'+componentId+' .gRotatorNav').css('top',heightOfPane);
```

}
is this correct because it is introducing inline styles and also in future we want all the styles and scripts in their own files .css, .less , .js rather than distributed among clientlibs in AEM.

I am more of Backend engineer but as a AEM developer I am touching the FED waters. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine, only that your jQuery code must run within a `$(document).ready()` to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before you start manipulating elements.

Also you might consider using jQuery's `outerHeight()` instead of `height()`as the latter does not include padding and borders.

```
$(function() {
    var heightOfPane = $('.pane').outerHeight();
    $('#'+componentId+' .gRotatorNav').css('top',heightOfPane);
});
```

Note: the syntax above is a shorthand for `$(document).ready()` so you can use it as is ([more info](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).

Comment: helped but used (function($){ }($)); to make $ available only in the scope. And checking on dom length for the $('idofelement').length>0{} and triggering the function which I created on the prototype. $.fn.adjustHeight = function(){ `above code` }